# How can I get this code to loop correctly?

Tags: c#

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give me a number");

    int h = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (c)
    {
        case 0:
            a = h;
            while (a <100 || a>250)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That number is too large");
                break;
            }

            break;

        case 1:
            b = h;
            while (a < 100 || a > 250)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That number is too large");
                break;
            }

            break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}",a+b);
Console.ReadKey();
```

When I input numbers greater than 250 or less than 100 it does give me the message ("That number is too large") but the problem is that it still executes the addition at the end of the code. I am trying to make it so that if those numbers fall outside of that range, it asks me again for the numbers. Any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: Your "breaking" of the switch.. and "breaking" of the loop... is confusing.

Comment: in `case 1:` `a` is always 0

Comment: Why do you have a `while` to match if the number is less than of bigger than? Those 2 while's are useless as they stand right now.

Comment: `while (condition) { … break; }` is equivalent to `if (condition) { … }`.

Answer (score 5):

Subroutines are wonderful things, and useful in many situations.

```
int GetNumberBetween( int minValue, int maxValue )
{
    int h;
    for (;;)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give me a number");
        h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if ( h >= minValue && h <= maxValue )
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("I don't like that number, try again");
    }
    return( h );
}

void DisplaySum( void )
{
    int a = GetNumberBetween( 100, 250 );
    int b = GetNumberBetween( 100, 250 );
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",a+b);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a better control on your external loop. Instead of a for use a while and increment the variable C only when you have a good number.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
while (c < 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give me a number");
    int h;
    if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out h)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
        continue;
    }
    switch (c)
    {
        case 0:
            a = h;
            if(a <100 || a>250)
                Console.WriteLine("That number is too large");
            else 
               c = 1;
            break;

        case 1:
            b = h;
            if(b < 100 || b > 250)
                 Console.WriteLine("That number is too large");
            else
               c = 2;
            break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}",a+b);
Console.ReadKey();
```

By the way, I suggest to use Int32.TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32 (What happen in your code if the user types something that cannot be converted to a number?)

I have also fixed a typo in your second test. You should use the variable b instead of a

Comment: That is correct. I fixed that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok I see what you did there. What does the c=1 and c=2 mean though?

Comment: They are needed to exit from the external loop (the first one). You enter the loop with c=0 and exit when `c=2`, if the var `a` is valid you pass to ask the input for `b` and set `c=1` when `b` is valid you set `c=2` and the external loop terminates. If something is not what you want the var `c` doesn't increment and you ask again to insert the correct value

Comment: Loop-switch for flow control? Eeek.

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking the solution. If you are just trying to sum two numbers, then simply do that. Think of it logically. You can add the error messages as needed.

1. Get the number for a
2. Get the number for b
3. Sum the numbers

Note: If you need to sum more than two numbers then this solution won't work

---

```
//...
int a = 0;

//Capture a value for a, and range check it
while (a < 10 || a > 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give me a number for (a)");
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

int b = 0;

//Capture a value for b, and range check it
while (b < 10 || b > 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give me a number for (b)");
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", a + b);
Console.ReadKey();
//...
```

---

EDIT:

```
int a = 0;

//Get a value for a
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give me a number for (a)");
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //Range check and exit if valid
    if (a >= 10 && a <= 50)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine("That number is too large");
}

int b = 0;

//Get a value for b
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give me a number for (b)");
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //Range check and exit if valid
    if (b >= 10 && b <= 50)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine("That number is too large");
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", a + b);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I am trying to add the numbers but heres my issue. If the number is not within the range I dont want it to add it. I want the system to tell me to try again with a number within a range. What it is currently doing is that if I pick a number out of the range it DOES tell me that the number is too large but it still adds it at the end.

Comment: Yeah there was an issue with the logic in your original code. Your original attempt seems to complex for a "simple" process. I've added another example showing how to handle error messages.